# Binded value on component.html {{cssURL}}, but the CSS is not loading

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call the CSS from a variable instead of hard coding it.

Below in my `pageview.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Full screen sections with CSS</title>
      <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">-->
      {{template_skeleton_top_param}} 
</head>

<body>
...//my content
</body>
</html>
```

The value of `{{template_skeleton_top_param}}` is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">`

My `pageview.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
this.template_skeleton_top_param = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">';
}
```

When calling from the variable, its not loading. If hard coding it, it's taking effect. In console.log(); the value of variable is also fine. I am unable to find the reason of not loading.

### Edit 1

Pasting my entire component and made a video to give a clear picture of what's happening:

```
export var myValue:any = null;

import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef,Renderer2,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

declare var $: any; //intentional use of jQuery

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editsection',
  templateUrl: './editsection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editsection.component.css']
})


export class EditsectionComponent implements OnInit {
public array_no1;
public dataArray;
public section_desc;
public get_template_skeleton; 
public template_skeleton_top_param;
public template_skeleton_top_param_test;
private contentEditable: boolean = false;

section: {id: number};

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private elRef: ElementRef,
  private el: ElementRef,
  private rd: Renderer2
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.el.nativeElement.innerHtml;      
}

  ngOnInit() {
    // insert the template code 
this.get_template_skeleton  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("templateType"));

this.template_skeleton_top_param_test = this.get_template_skeleton['template_code2'];
//console.log(this.template_skeleton_top_param_test);

this.template_skeleton_top_param = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/files/css/style.css">';
console.log(this.template_skeleton_top_param);

//this.document.body.innerHTML += this.get_template_skeleton.template_code2; //injecting HTML HERE
//this.document.body.innerHTML += "saurabh";
this.section = {id: this.route.snapshot.params['id']};
 var keys = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
  return /^section\d+$/.test(key);
});

 var dataArray = keys.map(function(key) {
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
});

for(var i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++){
    var array_no = dataArray[i];
}
 this.array_no1 = dataArray;
let obj2 = this.array_no1.find(obj2 => obj2.id == this.section.id);
this.section_desc = obj2.description;
//this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML = this.section_desc;  //injecting HTML HERE
//this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML += "abc";
  }

 selectDiv() {
     //create a new HTMLElement from nativeElement
    var hElement: HTMLElement = this.elRef.nativeElement;

    //now you can simply get your elements with their class name
  // var allDivs = hElement.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
var getSection = document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML;


    console.log("hii");
  //  console.log(allDivs);
    console.log(getSection);
   // $("h1[contenteditable='false']").attr('contenteditable', true)
   this.contentEditable = true;

  }

  DontEdit(){
    this.contentEditable = false;
  }

  //for clone
  clone(){
    console.log("Clone function here");
  }
   button2(){
    console.log("button2 function here");
  }


  // code for right click context menu
  rightPanelStyle: Object = {};

  detectRightMouseClick($event) {
    // disabling the default browser window which comes on right click
    document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());

       if($event.which === 3) {
            this.rightPanelStyle = {'display':'block','left':$event.clientX + 'px','top':$event.clientY + 'px'};
            return false;
       }
  }

  closeContextMenu() {
      this.rightPanelStyle = {'display':'none'};
  }

}
```

Video link: http://youtu.be/G_dAxijYRGY?hd=1

Comment: post your component

Comment: edited my question, please have a look, pasted my component and made a video for clear view too

Comment: you can't use angular bindings in the `head`;  The angular root does not include the `head` element.

Comment: what is the solution  ?

Comment: Why do you have to bind a CSS header in the first place?

Comment: it wouldn't really be feasible for angular to affect the head, since angular has to be loaded before it can change the document, and the head is the very first element that is executed, long before angular can ever be loaded into memory.  If you absolutely must have dynamic CSS loading, there are modules that can perform that task, but binding in the head isn't going to work.

Comment: Reason - I am making an HTML editor and the css files are placed in the assets folder, but which css will be used is dynamic because i have 6 stylesheets and according to logged in used the css needs to be called. I need some solution